# python3 requests отправляет запрос и ничего не происходит

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

у меня есть вот такой код:

```
import requests

header = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36 OPR/73.0.3856.424"}

r = requests.post("https://api.creditter.ru/confirm/sms/send", headers=header, json={"phone": "+7 (929) 920-88-**", "type": "register"})
print(r)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

но при отправке запроса смс не приходит
если вводить данные на сайт то всё приходит

post который я отправляю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пробовали добавлять cookie?

Comment: @Jack_oS нет, я только начинаю изучать requests можете написать код как это сделать?

Comment: также, в header, как "user-agent"

Comment: @Jack_oS сейчас попробую

Comment: @Jack_oS попробовал не работает

Comment: @Jack_oS header = {"cookie": "_ga=GA1.2.571165006.1617948265; _gid=GA1.2.248196476.1617948265; _ym_uid=1617948265169974258; _ym_d=1617948265; _ym_isad=2; sm_adv=cpc_brand_yandex; sm_uid=7228fccc-6bbe-4368-ba0c-8444c277ae8b; partner_affiliate=brand; jslbrc=w.202104090604467c8d9e70-98f9-11eb-bd1a-a69d17ca16b0.C_W; _ym_visorc=w"}           
это куки с post запроса

Comment: user-agent не выбрасывайте, оставьте в header

Comment: @Jack_oS вернул обратно не работает

Comment: что возвращается (r.content)?

Comment: @Jack_oS b'{\n    "isLimited": false,\n    "isSendCode": false\n}'

Comment: @Jack_oS  что я делаю не так?

Comment: Проверяйте через `filldler` или через средства разработчика в браузере какие запросы отправляются если через браузер общаться с сайтом.

Comment: @CrazyElf так и делал

Comment: @nn111666000 Ну надо как-то вот максимально сымитировать всё, что передаётся в "живых" запросах - и куки все и агент. Там что угодно могут с той стороны проверять, чтобы роботов не пустить, вплоть до размеров экрана и другой служебной инфы из заголовков.

Comment: На кой они сдались вместе со своими кредитами)?

Comment: Из важного пропущенного это, как минимум, заголовки `origin` и `referer`

Answer (score 0):

проблема была в том что нужно было дополнить запрос а именно нужно сделать вот так:

```
r = requests.post("https://api.creditter.ru/confirm/sms/send", 
    headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 
    Safari/537.36 OPR/73.0.3856.424", "x-ymclientid": цифры}, 
    json={"phone": "+7 (929) 920-88-**", "type": "register"})
```